# New installation of cmake "is not able to compile a simple test program."

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Cmake 3.5.1, and need to compile some C++ codes that needs Cmake 3.7. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I can't uninstall Cmake 3.5.1 as it is bundled with ROS and doing so will break ROS. Hence, I installed CMake 3.12.3 using the instructions from [here](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/) but in a different directory (/usr/local/cmake-3.12.3).

Running the commands in terminal to check versions:

> cmake version 3.12.3
>
> gcc version 5.4.0
>
> g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0

Next, I try to compile the C++ codes

```
cd /media/fastrl-master
sudo cmake .
```

I got an error that CMake is unable to compile a simple test program. I have tried setting the permissions of the folder containing the C++ codes (fastrl-master), and also to install build essentials (apt install --reinstall build-essential). These did not work.

This is the contents of CMakeError.log

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: --c++
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: --ec++
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: --c++
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3
>   Build flags:  Id flags: --ec++
>
> The output was: Permission denied
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler": Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did
>   not match "IAR .+ Compiler": Determining if the CXX compiler works
>   failed with the following output: Change Dir:
>   /media/fastrl-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_662e1/fast" /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/build
>   make[1](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/): Entering directory '/media/fastrl-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
>   /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3     -o
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c
>   /media/fastrl-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx make[1](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/):
>   execvp: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3: Permission denied
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o' failed make[1](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/): ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_662e1.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 127 make[1](https://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/cmake/):
>   Leaving directory '/media/fastrl-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_662e1/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_662e1/fast] Error 2

Comment: "Compiler: /usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3" - **Directory** `/usr/local/src/cmake-3.12.3` has been set as a **compiler** for CMake. This is definitely not a correct way for use CMake.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by adding -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++